# UART Receive Data Issue: MPLAB

Tags: c, gps, uart, mplab

I have a problem related to I am creating a GPS tracker (RX and UART2) and I am able to send the first packet of 1024 bytes via UART1 to PC. But when I try to recall the same function again, I run into the problem of the data not coming out correctly.

I am guessing this is something to do enabling interrupts, but not sure with UART.

Thanks

PS. Using PIC32MX440256H microcontrolller, MPLAB to write, GPS module to PIC UART2 RX and UART1 to display on PC.

Output to Serial (PC):

```
<CL>GPS DATA TRACKER V.1
<CL>next is GPS1
<CL>$GPGGA,164445.792,3753.2311,S,14440.0408,E,1,04,1.8,21.6,M,2.9,M,,0000*42
<CL>$GPGSA,A,3,13,20,10,16,,,,,,,,,4.2,1.8,3.8*30
<CL>$GPGSV,2,1,07,13,71,181,39,16,43,125,41,10,38,238,34,20,22,006,32*79
<CL>$GPGSV,2,2,07,19,05,053,34,27,00,000,38,30,00,000,28*45
<CL>$GPRMC,164445.792,A,3753.2311,S,14440.0408,E,000.0,000.0,180314,,,A*7C
<CL>$GPVTG,000.0,T,,M,000.0,N,000.0,K,A*0D
<CL>$GPGGA,164446.792,3753.2311,S,14440.0408,E,1,04,1.8,21.6,M,2.9,M,,0000*41
<CL>$GPGSA,A,3,13,20,10,16,,,,,,,,,4.2,1.8,3.8*30
<CL>$GPGSV,2,1,07,13,71,181,40,16,43,125,41,10,38,238,34,20,22,006,32*77
<CL>$GPGSV,2,2,07,19,05,053,35,27,00,000,38,30,00,000,28*44
<CL>$GPRMC,164446.792,A,3753.2311,S,14440.0408,E,000.0,000.0,180314,,,A*7F
<CL>$GPVTG,000.0,T,,M,000.0,N,000.0,K,A*0D
<CL>$GPGGA,164447.792,3753.2311,S,14440.0408,E,1,04,1.8,21.6,M,2.9,M,,0000*40
<CL>$GPGSA,A,3,13,20,10,16,,,,,,,,,4.2,1.8,3.8*30
<CL>$GPGSV,2,1,07,13,71,181,39,16,43,125,41,10,38,238,34,20,22,006,32*79
<CL>$GPGSV,2,2,07,19,05,053,34,27,00,000,38,30,00,000,28*45
<CL>$GPRMC,164447.792,A,3753.2311,S,14440.0408,E,000.0,00
<CL>next is GPS2
<CL>0.0,1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

Code:

```
int main (void)
{
TRISEbits.TRISE0 = 0; // for breadboard LED
LATEbits.LATE0 = OFF;

TRISDbits.TRISD1 = 0; // PINGUINO LED2
LATDbits.LATD1 = OFF;

mJTAGPortEnable(0); // Disable JTAG

// Turn on the interrupts
INTEnableSystemMultiVectoredInt();
SYSTEMConfigPerformance(GetSystemClock());
mOSCSetPBDIV(OSC_PB_DIV_2);

//UINT32 UART1DataReceived;

//UINT32 UART2DataReceived;

UARTConfigure(UART1, UART_ENABLE_PINS_TX_RX_ONLY);
UARTSetFifoMode(UART1, UART_INTERRUPT_ON_TX_NOT_FULL | UART_INTERRUPT_ON_RX_NOT_EMPTY);
UARTSetLineControl(UART1, UART_DATA_SIZE_8_BITS | UART_PARITY_NONE | UART_STOP_BITS_1);
UARTSetDataRate(UART1, GetPeripheralClock(), 9600);
UARTEnable(UART1, UART_ENABLE_FLAGS(UART_PERIPHERAL | UART_RX | UART_TX));

UARTConfigure(UART2, UART_ENABLE_PINS_TX_RX_ONLY);
UARTSetFifoMode(UART2, UART_INTERRUPT_ON_TX_NOT_FULL | UART_INTERRUPT_ON_RX_NOT_EMPTY);
UARTSetLineControl(UART2, UART_DATA_SIZE_8_BITS | UART_PARITY_NONE | UART_STOP_BITS_1);
UARTSetDataRate(UART2, GetPeripheralClock(), 9600);
UARTEnable(UART2, UART_ENABLE_FLAGS(UART_PERIPHERAL | UART_RX | UART_TX));

SendDataUART1("\r\n", strlen("\r\n"));
SendDataUART1("GPS DATA TRACKER V.1",strlen("GPS DATA TRACKER V.1"));
SendDataUART1("\r\n", strlen("\r\n"));





GetDataGPS(gps1, 1024);
SendDataUART1("next is GPS1", strlen("next is GPS1"));
SendDataUART1("\r\n", strlen("\r\n"));
Delay_ms(1000) ;
SendDataUART1(gps1, strlen(gps1));
SendDataUART1("\r\n", strlen("\r\n"));

Delay_ms(1000) ;

SendDataUART1("next is GPS2", strlen("next is GPS2"));
SendDataUART1("\r\n", strlen("\r\n"));

Delay_ms(1000) ;

GetDataGPS(gps2, 1024);

Delay_ms(1000) ;
SendDataUART1(gps2, strlen(gps2));
SendDataUART1("\r\n", strlen("\r\n"));

Delay_ms(1000) ;

while(1);
}



void SendDataUART1(const char *buffer, UINT32 size)
{
while(size)
{
    while(!UARTTransmitterIsReady(UART1))
        ;
    UARTSendDataByte(UART1, *buffer);
    buffer++;
    size--;
}
while(!UARTTransmissionHasCompleted(UART1))
    ;
}


UINT32 GetDataUART1(char *buffer, UINT32 max_size)
{
UINT32 num_char;

num_char = 0;

while(num_char < max_size)
{
    UINT8 character;

    while(!UARTReceivedDataIsAvailable(UART1))
        ;

    character = UARTGetDataByte(UART1);

    if(character == '\r')
        break;

    *buffer = character;

    buffer++;
    num_char++;
}

return num_char;
}


void SendDataUART2(const char *buffer, UINT32 size)
{
while(size)
{
    while(!UARTTransmitterIsReady(UART2))
        ;
    UARTSendDataByte(UART2, *buffer);
    buffer++;
    size--;
}
while(!UARTTransmissionHasCompleted(UART2))
    ;
}

UINT32 GetDataGPS(char *buffer, UINT32 max_size)
{
UINT32 num_char;


num_char = 0;

while(num_char < max_size)
{
    UINT8 character;

    while(!DataRdyUART2())
        ;

    character = ReadUART2();


   // if(character == '\r')
    // break;

    *buffer = character;

    buffer++;
    num_char++;
}

return num_char;

}
```

Comment: How are `gps1` and `gps2` definded?

Comment: Interrupts, what interrupts?  All I can see are what appear to be status-checking polling loops around calls like 'UARTTransmitterIsReady(UART1)'